# What is Django's TEMPLATE_DEBUG setting for?

Tags: django, debugging, django-templates

I have been trying to find information about this setting but there isn't much. Can someone explain me what is this setting about? Should I turn it off in production?... Just want to learn about it, maybe I'm missing something important in django.

(I use django 1.6)

Comment: Did you saw https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-debug?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**UPDATE** this is an excellent answer but it is out of date. See [the comment below by @iver56](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275252/what-is-djangos-template-debug-setting-for#comment53171797_25275285) for a more up-to-date answer.

(updated November 2023 by [@avi-flax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7012/avi-flax))

---

This setting helps with debugging errors/exceptions raised while rendering the templates.

If it is set to `True` and `DEBUG` is `True`, Django would show you usual "fancy" error page with a traceback, request details and other important information, and **highlight at which line the error happened**.

If it is set to `False` and `DEBUG` is `True` and there was an error while rendering the template, you would still see the Django's error page, but it would miss the block containing template code where the error occurred. So it would be more difficult to debug.

It is a good practice to make sure the value of `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` is the same as `DEBUG` (though if `DEBUG` is `False`, the error page would not be shown):

```
DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True   # development
DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False  # production
```

[Documentation reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-debug).

---

Example.

Imagine we have an error in the template, forgot to provide the date format in the `now` template tag:

```
<div>
    <span class="date">
        {% now %}
    </span>
</div>
```

`DEBUG` is set to `True`.

In case of `TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True` the Django's fancy error page would contain the following block:

[image]

If `TEMPLATE_DEBUG=False`, this block would not be visible.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` setting is deprecated in Django 1.8. The new way to do it is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32446043/2319697